# my Bootstrap columns have margins and paddings I can't remove

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with bootstrap and just found out that my bootstrap columns seem to have inbuilt padding and margins. How can I remove the default values? In the example I've attached I'd for instance like to a) reduce the distance between the orange and the blue division to 0px and b) remove the margin on the left and right.

[image]

Comment: give another class to that columns or id and add css margin:0px and padding:0px to it.

Comment: I tries adding that, but it does not work. My code is the following. Is there perhaps a problem in the HTML? 

<div class="background-section-grey">

 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 job-1"></div>

<div class="col-md-4"><div class="right-section">Lorem</div></div>
   
</div>
</div>

And the CSS is: 

.job-1 {
  background-color: $orange;
}

.background-section-grey {
  background-image: url("pic.png");
}

Comment: can you give snippet or fiddle? so i can see the issue about it.

Comment: Yes, sure. 

A fiddle is the code put in jsfiddle.net?
What would a snippet be?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use for one-off rows that I don't want padding on:

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

You could obviously apply it to all columns but honestly....I would think twice about it before you do it. Gutters are there for a reason. You don't want your text running right next to other text, etc.

Also, if you apply the background color directly to the column element instead of an element inside the column, the background colors will touch but there will still be padding inside for text.

Lastly, be careful about removing the margins on the left and right. Every column should be in a row and every row should be in a container. The container has a default margin of +15 on each side. The row has a margin of -15. The columns have a +15. This allows content directly in a container and content in a column to be aligned in a straight vertical line down the page. Otherwise you have things hopping left and right and it looks odd.

Nothing should ever go directly in a row. It's either in a container or a column.

Comment: It is very interesting

Answer (score 1):

Since bootstrap is class-based styling framework, just inject some css of your own inside theirs. https://jsfiddle.net/f98ctLy5/ (Make sure to zoom out, because bootstrap is by default responsive.)

**HTML/Bootstrap**

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8 main'>Sample</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 child'>Side</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-color:#999;
        }

.child {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-color:#ccc;
        }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad to hear that!! Take care! :)

Answer (score 1):

> a) reduce the distance between the orange and the blue division to 0px

You can [**customize your Bootstrap here**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) and make `@grid-gutter-width` variable `0px`. That way you don't need to add extra classes to your HTML.

> b) remove the margin on the left and right

For full width layout always use [`.container-fluid`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid) class instead of `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and get rid of the div (class = row) containing the columns

Edit: you can leave the row there, but apply `padding:0` to the column div that has an inner div within it

Anyway I am not too sure as I am on my phone but I reckon you didn't close the outermost div

Comment: Tried. but it doesn't make a difference. I added my code on top.

Comment: You have to eliminate the padding in the inner div inside one of the colums

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <style>
    .man{
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    .shi{
      background-color: violet;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="man col-xs-6">Lorem</div>
  <div class="shi col-xs-6">Ipsum</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this is what you want, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.col-xs-8{
  background-color:red;
}
.col-xs-4{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      lorem
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```